# Fontawesome briefcase styles

Tags: fontawesome

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document}
  \faBriefcase[light]
  \faBriefcase[regular]
  \faBriefcase[solid]  
\end{document}
```

Fontawesome site shows 3 styles for the briefcase icon:
https://origin.fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=briefcase

But I can't get them to work in my document, this code shows the same icon repeated 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the solid version of the briefcase symbol is available in the free version of the awesome font. If you want to use the other versions, you need the `pro` version

You can see this from the warnings you get:

```
Package fontawesome5 Warning: The requested icon briefcase has been replaced
(fontawesome5)                by the solid version


Package fontawesome5 Warning: The requested icon briefcase has been replaced
(fontawesome5)                by the solid version
```

Or by hovering over the symbols on the website you link to:

[image]

(notice the little "pro" in the top right corner)

Comment: Thanks @book. I spent half a day migrating to sid to be able to use fontawesome5 just for this.

Comment: @Rod Maybe a vanilla texlive installation would have spared you a migration to sid?

Comment: I think so, but I also had some issues trying to install the package locally to my document not globally